# Is there a way to test websites for iOS Safari other than simulator (which is acting different from real iPhone)?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, safari, ios-simulator

I have the iOS simulator and the website I'm testing works perfectly in it, but other testers with real iphones are seeing problems. Is there anything that can make the simulator act the same or another app that can correctly simulate iOS Safari?

Comment: what problems are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Simulator and device are pretty close.  With the iOS 8.0 simulator, almost all of the stack is built from the same code as the device iOS.  The only possible differences are very low level libraries (libsystem_pthread.dylib, libsystem_platform.dylib, and libsystem_kernel.dylib).  None of those should be significantly different between sim and device.  Please be as specific as possible, and I suggest you file a radar as well at http://bugreport.apple.com